# Build Ruby on Rails apps with Microsoft Graph Tutorial OmniAuth::AuthenticityError Forbidden Erros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, microsoft-graph-api, omniauth

I am a complete newbie to Rails and Microsoft Graph/Omniauth etc and have become a bit stuck.

I have followed the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/ruby Build Ruby on Rails apps with Microsoft Graph Tutorial word for word. On the Add Azure AD authentication Implement sign-in where I get to start the server should be redirected to https://login.microsoftonline.com I get:

`OmniAuth::AuthenticityError Forbidden.`

I do not get directed to the login my URL is: http://localhost:3000/auth/microsoft_graph_auth when displaying the above error.

I am running Ruby 2.7. and not 2.6.6 (as stated in the documentation).

Does anyone have any pointers and/or advice?

Thanks in advance!

```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
omniauth (2.0.1) lib/omniauth/authenticity_token_protection.rb:27:in `deny'
rack-protection (2.1.0) lib/rack/protection/base.rb:54:in `react'
omniauth (2.0.1) lib/omniauth/authenticity_token_protection.rb:18:in `call!'
omniauth (2.0.1) lib/omniauth/authenticity_token_protection.rb:11:in `call'
omniauth (2.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:236:in `request_call'
omniauth (2.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:192:in `call!'
omniauth (2.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
omniauth (2.0.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:45:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.3.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.3.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.3.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
webpacker (4.3.0) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
puma (4.3.7) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.7) lib/puma/server.rb:713:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.7) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.7) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.7) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
Request
Parameters:

{"_method"=>"post", "authenticity_token"=>"lAY5YLY5Lx8xv4+iyfDk/MuG6OwqBn6vUrzUEw26qw/1ZrdKCupamEKdDbpwK+8s5qjM7YntYffqLTwPB1jtsQ=="}
Toggle session dump
_csrf_token: "8gciHGHmLp07eqP3Qs8CZrjW2xhBqQ6yHsweK9pMOkM="
csrf: "95lfFRsk0iDvSyekGINXdb/tmKszz7i4ksTVwgU2vf0="
omniauth.params: {}
Toggle env dump
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.2"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate, br"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7"
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: "max-age=0"
HTTP_ORIGIN: "http://localhost:3000"
HTTP_VERSION: "HTTP/1.1"
ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_NAME: ""
REMOTE_ADDR: "::1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: It is hard to guess what is wrong here. To me it seems like something is wrong in your permissions settings on Microsoft side. Have you checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors

Comment: Share the requestid, timestamp, detailed error info of the Graph API call.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have posted the dump info, any pointers on how to get the requestid, timestamp, detailed error?

Comment: What is the URL in your browser when you get this error? Is this after you click the Sign In button, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I click the signin button and then get redirected to this error the URL is: http://localhost:3000/auth/microsoft_graph_auth. 

I think this error is before even getting redirected to https://login.microsoftonline.com.....etc

Answer (score 8):

Actually, I had this same error.
The cause was the gem onmiauth, which is a dependency of omniauth-oauth2 was installed as v2.0.2 and there were breaking changes from version 1.9.1

I added the following line to my Gemfile:

`gem 'omniauth', '~> 1' # load highest level of omniauth v1, 1.9.1 at the time of this post`

Then run `bundle update` to update the versions used in the app.

Run the server with `rails server` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input, basically I rebuilt the whole environment rails included and now its working (so it must have been human error on myside!